# How to add Progress Dialog Box

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I'm using  `Fragment` to Display the Movies name, poster and reviews and Trailer using `API` key. I am trying to add `progressbar` such that when the `RecyclerView` is loading it will display the progress bar and when loading is complete..it will become invisible.

I tried to put various method but it always gives me error or app  compiles and run but crashes.

Below is my `MoviesUtil` class file

```html
public class MoviesUtil {
    private static final Webb WEBB = Webb.create();

    private static final String TMDB_API_MOVIES_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/%s?api_key=%s&page=%s";
    private static final String TMDB_API_VIDEOS_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/%s/videos?api_key=%s";
    private static final String TMDB_API_REVIEWS_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/%s/reviews?api_key=%s";
    private static final String TMDB_POSTER_URL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185%s";
    private static final String TMDB_BACKDROP_URL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300%s";

    private static final String TYPE_POPULAR = "popular";
    private static final String TYPE_TOP_RATED = "top_rated";
    private static final String TYPE_FAVORITES = "favorites";


    public static boolean isFavorite(Context context, Movie movie) {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                .query(MovieContract.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        String.format("%s = ? and %s = ?", MovieContract.MOVIE_ID, MovieContract.TYPE),
                        new String[]{movie.getId() + "", TYPE_FAVORITES},
                        null
                );
        boolean isFavorite = cursor.getCount() > 0;
        cursor.close();
        return isFavorite;
    }



    public static boolean toggleFavorite(Context context, Movie movie) {
        if (isFavorite(context, movie)) {
            deleteMovie(context, TYPE_FAVORITES, movie);
            return false;
        } else {
            saveMovie(context, TYPE_FAVORITES, movie);
            return true;
        }
    }



    public static void getPopularMovies(Activity activity, MoviesCallback callback) {
        getMovies(activity, TYPE_POPULAR, callback);

    }

    public static void getTopRatedMovies(Activity activity, MoviesCallback callback) {
        getMovies(activity, TYPE_TOP_RATED, callback);
    }

    public static void getFavoritesMovies(Activity activity, MoviesCallback callback) {
        getMovies(activity, TYPE_FAVORITES, callback);
    }

    private static void getMovies(final Activity activity, final String type, final MoviesCallback callback) {
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (Util.isConnected(activity, false) && !type.equals(TYPE_FAVORITES)) {
                    getMoviesFromApi(activity, type);
                }
                getMoviesFromDb(activity, type, callback);




            }
        });
    }

    private static void getMoviesFromApi(Activity activity, String type) {
        String apiUrl = String.format(TMDB_API_MOVIES_URL, type, activity.getString(R.string.tmdb_api_key), 1);
        try {
            JSONArray moviesJson = WEBB.get(apiUrl)
                    .asJsonObject()
                    .getBody()
                    .getJSONArray("results");

            List<Movie> movies = toMovies(activity, moviesJson);
            deleteMovies(activity, type);
            saveMovies(activity, type, movies);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    private static void getMoviesFromDb(Activity activity, String type, final MoviesCallback callback) {
        try {
            Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver()
                    .query(MovieContract.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            MovieContract.TYPE + " = ?",
                            new String[]{type},
                            null

                    );
            final List<Movie> movies = toMovies(cursor);
            cursor.close();
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    callback.success(movies);

                }
            });
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    callback.error(e);
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public static void getReviewsFromApi(final Activity activity, final Movie movie, final ReviewsCallback callback) {
        if (Util.isConnected(activity, false)) {
            AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String apiUrl = String.format(TMDB_API_REVIEWS_URL, movie.getId(), activity.getString(R.string.tmdb_api_key));
                    final List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();
                    try {
                        JSONArray reviewsJson = WEBB.get(apiUrl)
                                .asJsonObject()
                                .getBody()
                                .getJSONArray("results");
                        reviews.addAll(toReviews(reviewsJson));
                    } catch (final Exception e) {
                        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                callback.error(e);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    if (reviews.isEmpty()) {
                        Review review = new Review();
                        review.setContent(activity.getString(R.string.no_review_found));
                        reviews.add(review);
                    }
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            callback.success(reviews);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            Review review = new Review();
            review.setContent(activity.getString(R.string.conn_internet));
            final List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();
            reviews.add(review);
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    callback.success(reviews);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private static void saveMovie(final Context context, final String type, final Movie movie) {
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
                movies.add(movie);
                saveMovies(context, type, movies);
            }
        });
    }

    private static void saveMovies(Context context, String type, List<Movie> movies) {
        if (movies != null) {
            ContentValues[] moviesValues = new ContentValues[movies.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < movies.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    Movie movie = movies.get(i);
                    ContentValues movieValues = new ContentValues();
                    movieValues.put(MovieContract.MOVIE_ID, movie.getId());
                    movieValues.put(MovieContract.TYPE, type);
                    movieValues.put(MovieContract.TITLE, movie.getTitle());
                    movieValues.put(MovieContract.OVERVIEW, movie.getOverview());
                    movieValues.put(MovieContract.POSTER_URL, movie.getPosterUrl());
                    movieValues.put(MovieContract.BACKDROP_URL, movie.getBackdropUrl());
                    movieValues.put(MovieContract.TRAILER_URL, movie.getTrailerUrl());
                    movieValues.put(MovieContract.RELEASE_DATE, Util.toDbDate(movie.getReleaseDate()));
                    movieValues.put(MovieContract.RATING, movie.getRating());
                    movieValues.put(MovieContract.ADULT, movie.isAdult() ? 1 : 0);
                    moviesValues[i] = movieValues;
                } catch (Exception ignore) {
                }
            }
            context.getContentResolver()
                    .bulkInsert(MovieContract.CONTENT_URI, moviesValues);
        }
    }

    private static void deleteMovie(final Context context, final String type, final Movie movie) {
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                context.getContentResolver()
                        .delete(MovieContract.CONTENT_URI,
                                MovieContract.MOVIE_ID + " = ? and " + MovieContract.TYPE + " = ?",
                                new String[]{movie.getId() + "", type});
            }
        });
    }

    private static void deleteMovies(final Context context, final String type) {
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                context.getContentResolver()
                        .delete(MovieContract.CONTENT_URI,
                                MovieContract.TYPE + " = ?",
                                new String[]{type});
            }
        });
    }

    private static List<Movie> toMovies(Cursor cursor) {
        List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Movie movie = new Movie();
            movie.setId(cursor.getInt(
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.MOVIE_ID)));
            movie.setTitle(cursor.getString(
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.TITLE)));
            movie.setOverview(cursor.getString(
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.OVERVIEW)));
            movie.setPosterUrl(cursor.getString(
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.POSTER_URL)));
            movie.setBackdropUrl(cursor.getString(
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.BACKDROP_URL)));
            movie.setTrailerUrl(cursor.getString(
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.TRAILER_URL)));
            movie.setReleaseDate(Util.toDate(cursor.getString(
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.RELEASE_DATE))));
            movie.setRating(cursor.getFloat(
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.RATING)));
            movie.setAdult(cursor.getInt(
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.ADULT)) == 1);
            movies.add(movie);
        }
        return movies;
    }

    private static List<Movie> toMovies(Context context, JSONArray jsonMovies) {
        List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
        if (jsonMovies != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMovies.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonMovie = jsonMovies.getJSONObject(i);
                    int movieId = jsonMovie.getInt("id");
                    Movie movie = new Movie();
                    movie.setId(movieId);
                    movie.setTitle(jsonMovie.getString("title"));
                    movie.setOverview(jsonMovie.getString("overview"));
                    movie.setPosterUrl(String.format(TMDB_POSTER_URL, jsonMovie.getString("poster_path")));
                    movie.setBackdropUrl(String.format(TMDB_BACKDROP_URL, jsonMovie.getString("backdrop_path")));
                    movie.setTrailerUrl(getTrailerUrl(context, movieId));
                    movie.setReleaseDate(Util.toDate(jsonMovie.getString("release_date")));
                    movie.setRating((float) jsonMovie.getDouble("vote_average"));
                    movie.setAdult(jsonMovie.getBoolean("adult"));
                    movies.add(movie);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return movies;
    }

    private static List<Review> toReviews(JSONArray jsonReviews) {
        List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();
        if (jsonReviews != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonReviews.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonReview = jsonReviews.getJSONObject(i);
                    Review review = new Review();
                    review.setAuthor(jsonReview.getString("author"));
                    review.setContent(jsonReview.getString("content"));
                    reviews.add(review);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return reviews;
    }

    private static String getTrailerUrl(Context context, int movieId) {
        String apiUrl = String.format(TMDB_API_VIDEOS_URL, movieId, context.getString(R.string.tmdb_api_key));
        try {
            JSONArray trailersJson = WEBB.get(apiUrl)
                    .asJsonObject()
                    .getBody()
                    .getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < trailersJson.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject trailerJson = trailersJson.getJSONObject(i);
                if (trailerJson.getString("site").toLowerCase().equals("youtube")) {
                    return "https://youtube.com/watch?v=" + trailerJson.getString("key");
                }
            }
            return "";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    }

}
```

and my `Fragment` class is

```html
public class MoviesFragment extends BaseFragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener,
        RecyclerItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener {
    private static final String ARG_FRAG_TYPE = "fragType";
    private static final String ARG_FRAG_TWO_PANE = "twoPane";



    public enum Type {
        POPULAR,
        TOP_RATED,
        FAVORITES
    }

    @State
    ArrayList<Movie> movies;
    @State
    Type fragType;
    @State
    boolean twoPane;


    @BindView(R.id.refresh)
    SwipeRefreshLayout refreshView;
    @BindView(R.id.movies)
    RecyclerView moviesView;

    public static MoviesFragment newInstance(Type fragType, boolean twoPane) {
        MoviesFragment fragment = new MoviesFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_FRAG_TYPE, fragType);
        args.putBoolean(ARG_FRAG_TWO_PANE, twoPane);
        fragment.setArguments(args);





        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Icepick.restoreInstanceState(this, savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            fragType = (Type) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_FRAG_TYPE);
            twoPane = getArguments().getBoolean(ARG_FRAG_TWO_PANE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies_list, container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
        init();
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        movies = null;
        updateMovies();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
        showMovieAtPosition(position);
    }

    @Subscribe(sticky = true)
    public void onEvent(UpdateFavoritesEvent event) {
        if (fragType == Type.FAVORITES) {
            EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(UpdateFavoritesEvent.class);
            onRefresh();
        }
    }

    @Subscribe(sticky = true)
    public void onEvent(TwoPaneEvent event) {
        twoPane = event.twoPane;
    }

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        RecyclerItemClickSupport.addTo(moviesView)
                .setOnItemClickListener(this);
        moviesView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2));
        moviesView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        refreshView.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        updateMovies();
    }

    private void updateMovies() {
        if (movies == null) {
            MoviesCallback callback = new MoviesCallback() {
                @Override
                public void success(List<Movie> result) {
                    movies = new ArrayList<>(result);
                    if (moviesView != null) {
                        moviesView.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(getContext(), movies));
                    }
                    refreshView.setRefreshing(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void error(Exception error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    refreshView.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            };
            switch (fragType) {
                case POPULAR:
                    MoviesUtil.getPopularMovies(getActivity(), callback);

                    break;
                case TOP_RATED:
                    MoviesUtil.getTopRatedMovies(getActivity(), callback);
                    break;
                case FAVORITES:
                    MoviesUtil.getFavoritesMovies(getActivity(), callback);
                    break;
            }
        } else if (moviesView != null) {
            moviesView.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(getContext(), movies));
            refreshView.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }

    private void showMovieAtPosition(int position) {
        if (movies != null && position <= movies.size() - 1) {
            Movie movie = movies.get(position);
            EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new ShowMovieEvent(movie));
            if (twoPane) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.movie_detail, new MovieFragment())
                        .commit();
            } else {
                startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), MovieActivity.class));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the error message.

Comment: @Tepits sorry for my late reply here is the thread I earlier opened..Here I have edited my question and posted the error cord please check ..if your answer could be any helpful ..I'll upvote for you in both Thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138567/set-progress-bar-when-java-class-method-is-complete-in-android/52138921?noredirect=1#comment91305247_52138921